# Dynamics 365 CRM Portals. Rich-text editor missing

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, adxstudio-portals, dynamics-crm-portals

I work with Dynamics 365 Portals.
The rich-text editor is missing, how do I get it back?

I (my user) have all four webroles, including administrator. I am logged in. I have tried to clearing all cashes and reboot the portal itself. My coleagues are also unable to see it. Nothing works.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Is clicking edit not going to open the rich text editor?

Comment: The image shown is showing the actual editor. It is the whole thing that is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things to check.

1. There should only be a [single Authenticated web role and a single Anonymous web role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/portals/create-web-roles). You don't need to assign these web roles to your user, they are applied automatically by context.
2. [Check you have a web page access control rule setup to grant change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/portals/webpage-access-control), that is linked to your Administrator web role.
3. Make sure you clear the [server side cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/portals/clear-server-side-cache).

Comment: Thank you @James Wood. Point 2, this solved the issue. I had to create a brand new rule. For some for a year we have been running with default settings. So suddently needing to change them was surprising. Perhaps something changed/broke during one of many updates.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I do not have enough reputations to comment.
I am assuming that you don't see the front side editing tools.

9 out of 10 times, this is typically to do with the cache not clearing properly. Could you changing something on the webpage and check if the cache is clearing properly and the newest webpage content is surfacing on the portal?

Also, by default, the "Administrator" web role is associated with the appropriate "Website Access Permission" to provide you with the front side editing capability. If for some reason, the Website Access Permission is not associated with the Administrator web role, even if you belong to the Administrator web role, front side editing capability will not work.

Comment: +1 because of the 90 % success rate with clearing the cache. This is the first thing someone with this issue should try.

Comment: Note. If clearing the cache does not help, one can also try to reset the portal. This sometimes helps as well. beware that the portal will be unavailable for a few minutes.